# Breakpoints remaining after deleting them from VS using TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013

It seems that breakpoints are being saved when files get checked-in in VS. So what happens is that someone else will check in a file with a breakpoint and then I will get the latest. It will have their breakpoints in it. This seems weird? And whats more weird is that if you delete them they go away during that debugging session but come back.

Is this a bug? If not, how do I get rid of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breakpoints aren't checked in. They are saved in your user options file (MySolution.suo) and are local to your machine. If you delete that file, the breakpoints will disappear.

SUO stands for Solution User Options, and should not be added to source control.

Comment: So would this be a bug then because these are breakpoints in files that I hadn't worked in but got the latest of?

Comment: Do you guys check in the .suo file into source control? If you do and you get latest version of the .suo file that someone else checked in (and set breakpoints etc.) then you would get their breakpoints.

Comment: I don't see that file in TFS source control explorer but when I deleted the file from my computer the mysterious breakpoints went away.

Comment: VS 2015. Just got latest version of source. Got a breakpoint from another user. The .suo is not in TFS.